# Excon::Error::Forbidden: Expected(200) <=> Actual(403 Forbidden) with rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, sitemap, bucket

I would like to create a sitemap through sitemap_generator. I'm also under heroku so I need to use an S3 bucket. When I `rake sitemap:refresh`.

```
Excon::Error::Forbidden: Expected(200) <=> Actual(403 Forbidden)
excon.error.response:body          => "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>3S4SFR8RBS6K7M1T</RequestId>
<HostId>gbVL7m0enEx9rRqnLCzoqoJpqYzHvtIob7XQq2Jvev/szSchY6faoKOF5vAKgq0RKe0cRyDI/4I=</HostId>
</Error>"
```

I don't know how to handle this problem. When I try to change to AWS policy it explains me that AWS is the only one to handle this things.

Does anyone already faced this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Probably you didn't configure your bucket for public read access (or you did but forgot to allow such a policy, which is a separate setting)

Comment: Perfect I finally found it, I was updating to public another option. Thank you